# Error al crear mi primera aplicación en android studio

Tags: gradle

acabo de instalar android studio, y al calgar la aplicaión me da el error que muestro a continuación.

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/externalSystem/model/ExternalSystemException

saludos y gracias.

Comment: parece ser un error de android studio, te recomiendo reportarlo en https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

Comment: y voto por cerrar esta pregunta debido a que es un error de tu IDE, no un error de programacion. Te recomiendo reinstalar tu IDE y leer el articulo https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic